# input shape of dataset in cnn

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, theano

My dataset is a simple table of 20 columns and 100,000 rows.It is not a image data as commonly used in CNN.
What input shape should I provide in this case?

Right now I did-

```
input_shape = (21,109713,1)
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
```

which gives the error-

```
ValueError: rng_mrg cpu-implementation does not support more than (2**31 -1) samples
```

full code-

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


class AccuracyHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.acc = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.acc.append(logs.get('acc'))

history = AccuracyHistory()

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[history])
```

Comment: Try giving the shape as (109713,21,1)

Comment: @HariKrishnan its giving ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (109713, 19)

Comment: You are using a cnn, hence the network expects the input to be 4 dimensions i.e (number_of_rows,height,width,channel)

Comment: @HariKrishnan yes but CNN can be used for non image data also right?

Comment: Yes, but i think you still have to use a four dimensional dataset

Comment: or you can try reshaping your data set ti 4 dimensional one. Another option is to give input_shape parameter inside Conv2d

Comment: @HariKrishnan I did just that...I attached the full code

Comment: Why do you want to use a 2d concolution? What is your data?